# Regular expression to match any number except for one containing repeated zeros

Tags: python, regex

I want to match large numbers in my data but sometimes the data includes repeated zeros for emphasis rather than phone numbers. How can I identify numbers at least nine digits long and not include any numbers with repeated zeros (say, at least 5)? For example:

match: call me at 19083910893

don't match: this x1000000000

I tried `[0-9]+(?!0+)` but this isn't what I need because the negative lookahead doesn't unmatch results found with the `[0-9]+`. Somehow, `(\d)(?!0+)\d+` works in tests but I don't really understand why.

Comment: Should `19083910093` match or not?

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
(?<!\d)(?!\d*0{5})\d{9,}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\d)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a digit directly to the left
- `(?!\d*0{5})` Assert that at the right are not 5 zeroes
- `\d{9,}` Match 9 or more digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/You6SM/1)